# html elements not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

This Meteor html code failed to show the `password-reset-form` when the `click #password-reset-form-link` is clicked. I looked every where for no avail. Could you please help me find the cause? Thanks

```js
'click #login-form-link': function (event) {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
    $("#password-reset-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#password-reset-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  'click #register-form-link': function (event) {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $("#password-reset-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#password-reset-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  'click #password-reset-form-link': function (event) {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $("#password-reset-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $(event.target).addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  'click #forgot': function () {
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $("#password-reset-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $('#password-reset-form-link').addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 90px;
}
.panel-login {
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
    color: #00415d;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
    color: #029f5b;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
    background-color: #59B2E0;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #53A3CD;
    border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
    background-color: #1CB94E;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-color: #1CB94A;
}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1CA347;
    border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container" id="login-div">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-login">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="#" class="" id="password-reset-form-link">Password reset</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form id="login-form" role="form" style="display: block;">
                  <p>login form</p>
                </form>
                <form id="register-form" role="form" style="display: none;">
                  <p>register form</p>
                </form>
                <form id="#password-reset-form" role="form" style="display: none;">
                  <p>hi man</p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your HTML:

```
<form id="#password-reset-form" ...>
```

The `#` shouldn't be there:

```
<form id="password-reset-form" ...>
```